# How to save the data of JSON file in local path to a SQL table?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to save the data of JSON file which is in my local path to a SQL table.

My Local Path where the JSON file is present is E:\20180824LocalDump.json

I have used the below code in SQL to get the data from JSON file but I got errors.

```
DECLARE @Details VARCHAR(MAX)  
SELECT @Details = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\20180824LocalDump.json', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON;   
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Details)   
WITH(Departure_airport nvarchar(50)  ,
    DisplayName nvarchar(40), 
    Email nvarchar(60),
    Keep_me_deals nvarchar(40),
    Phone_Code nvarchar(50),
    Provider nvarchar(50),
    SignUpDate nvarchar(50),
    Telephone nvarchar(50),
    [Platform] nvarchar(50),
    AppVersion nvarchar(40))
```

Created a table as shown below:

```
Create Table Dump
(
Departure_airport nvarchar(50),
DisplayName nvarchar(40),
Email nvarchar(60),
Keep_me_deals nvarchar(40),
Phone_Code nvarchar(50),
Provider nvarchar(50),
SignUpDate nvarchar(50),
Telephone nvarchar(50),
[Platform] nvarchar(50),
AppVersion nvarchar(40)
)
```

My Json file contents:

```
[{"Departure_airport":"Test","DisplayName":"Test","Email":"Tst","Keep_me_deals":"Test","Phone_Code":"Test","Provider":"Test","SignUpDate":"Test","Telephone":"Test","Platform":"Test","AppVersion":"Test"},{"Departure_airport":"Test","DisplayName":"Test","Email":"Tst","Keep_me_deals":"Test","Phone_Code":"Test","Provider":"Test","SignUpDate":"Test","Telephone":"Test","Platform":"Test","AppVersion":"Test"},{"Departure_airport":"Test for IE","DisplayName":"Test for IE","Email":"Tst for IE","Keep_me_deals":"Test for IE","Phone_Code":"Test for IE","Provider":"Test for IE","SignUpDate":"Test for IE","Telephone":"Test for IE","Platform":"Test for IE","AppVersion":"Test for IE"},{"Departure_airport":"Test for UK","DisplayName":"Test for UK","Email":"Tst for UK","Keep_me_deals":"Test for UK","Phone_Code":"Test for UK","Provider":"Test for UK","SignUpDate":"Test for UK","Telephone":"Test for UK","Platform":"Test for UK","AppVersion":"Test for UK"},{"Departure_airport":"Test for UK 1","DisplayName":"Test for UK 1","Email":"Tst for UK 1","Keep_me_deals":"Test for UK 1","Phone_Code":"Test for UK 1","Provider":"Test for UK 1","SignUpDate":"Test for UK 1","Telephone":"Test for UK 1","Platform":"Test for UK 1","AppVersion":"Test for UK 1"}]
```

I am getting an error like:

> Invalid object name 'OPENJSON' in SQL.

Please help me on this

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? `OPENJSON` only works starting from version 2016

Comment: I am using version 2014

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL 2016 or later, you should also check the compatibility level of the database you are running the query from.

```
USE <your database>;  
GO  
SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '<your database>';  
GO
```

If it is not at least 130 you need to (with the kind permission of your DBA) change it.

```
ALTER DATABASE <your database> SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130;  
GO
```

You probably want to Google for other effects of changing the compatibility level, but it's never caused me a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use `openjson` with SQL Server 2014: native json function have been introduced with SQL Server 2016 (more info on openjson [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql)).

An excerpt from the linked page:

> APPLIES TO: Server (**starting with 2016**)

You can still import the json file with `OPENROWSET`, but you will have to rely on string manipulation functions or on custom functions to extract data from you json file.